# Inner class of Layouts in Android

Tags: java, android

Probably this is really stupid question but i created structure like this and i really have issues with performance.

```
public class OuterClass extends LinearLayout {

private LinearLayout viewPort;

public OuterClass(Context context) {
    super(context);     
    initComponents(context);
    addInnerClass();
}

private void initComponents(Context context){

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().
        getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);      
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_port, this);     
    viewPort = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_port);     
}

private void addInnerClass(){

    for ( int i = 0; i < k; i++ ){
        InnerClass functio = this.new InnerClass();
        viewPort.addView(functio);
    }

}
    private class InnerClass extends RelativeLayout{

    private LineraLayout newLines; 

    public InnerClass() {
        super(OuterClass.this.context);     
        initComponents(OuterClass.this.context);
        addNLines();
    }

    private void initComponents(Context context){

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        inflater.inflate(R.layout.job_function_container, this);

        newLines = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.newLines);          

    }

    private void addInnerOfInner(View view){
        newLines.addView(view);
    }

    private void addNLines(){

        for ( int i = 0; i < k1; i++ ){
            InnerOfInnerClass line = this.new InnerOfInnerClass();
            addInnerOfInner(line);
        }

    }

        public class InnerOfInnerClass extends RelativeLayout{


            private InnerOfInnerClass(){
                super(OuterClass.this.context);             
                initComponents(OuterClass.this.context);
            }

            private void initComponents(Context context){

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_line, this);

                // Setting some fields.
            }               

        }   

    }
```

}

To be more spesific it is realy slow if i will try to create 5 InnerClass objects and 5 of InnerOfInner Class objects in each InnerClass.  I would be extremely grateful if some one will explain me why. Thx.

Comment: You have a addInner() method but do not show that method's definition. Did you mean it to be addInnerOfInner()?

Comment: What is in the layouts your inflating? The more layers of views you have the worse the performance will get. Usually the rule of thumb is 3 layers deep, any deeper and you have to tread carefully.

Comment: Sorry my bad i changed names and made mistake. Should be addNLines() function in InnerClass constructor.

Comment: So do you think it's because of amount of layouts, not because objects has to be initialized inside another objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything that stands out from your code as a huge red flag. As to why it's really slow in the creation part could be for a variety of reasons. Things to consider:

1. How is OuterClass being instantiated from the activity? Is it only being called once or are you creating several instances. The more you have the slower it'll be.
2. How many other widgets are on the R.layout.new_line, R.layout.job_function_container, R.layout.view_port? Having just one widget vs 50 on each may cause some noticeable delays.
3. What device are you testing with? Running on a old Droid will be significantly slower then testing on a Nexus 7. If your using an emulator...well, always expect everything to run slow.
4. Finally (and probably the most pertinent), I believe the biggest slow down is the complexity or the depth of your nesting layouts.  As Ancantus mentioned, try to avoid deep layout layers. Go too deep, and weird things may start to happen. Mostly due to the amount of memory such hierarchies consume.

If you need a dynamic means of adding views, I'd suggest looking into a ListView, GridView, or even a GridLayout if your target platform allows. Off the top of my head, I can't think of why you would require such a complex design. Though there are special case needs, usually there's always an easier, more correct way.

Here's some helpful links on Layout Optimization that may or may not be helpful for you:

- [Layout Trick 1](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html)
- [Layout Trick 2](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html)
- [Layout Trick 3](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html)
- [Layout Trick 4](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-with.html)

Comment: Thx for answer. I will try to change structure to avoid thus inner classes. OuterClass called only once. There 5 TextEdit in R.layout.new_line and 2 elements in R.layout.job_function_container. I understand that it's too much elements in one View but because of structure of the app  it's hard to avoid it. For testing i use Samsung Galaxy 10.1

Comment: No prob. If possible, I'd also try to move as much of it as you can to XML layouts instead of doing it programmatically. Easier to optimize layout there. The Tab is about average so it shouldn't be a cause of the slow down. Also, please accept my answer if it's up to your satisfaction.

Comment: if you don't mind one more question. A am begginer with android and i don't know what i sopoust to do if i need to be able to add element dynamically. Something like click on the button and you get new TextEdit. A lot of them.

Comment: You mean like adding a TextView dynamically? Use the *.addView() method. IE: viewPort.addView(INSERT VIEW OBJECT HERE).

Comment: Actually i mean what to do if you need a lot of objects in one View. More than 50. But any way doesn't mind.

Comment: Also: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews